# Interactive Plot py

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, ipywidgets

I want to code a interactive plot but there are some problems.

```
import ipywidgets as w
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def joo(a=1):
  x = np.linspace(0, 20, 21).reshape(1, -1)
  y = np.sin(2*a)
  plt.plot(x, y)
  plt.grid()
  plt.show()
w.interact(joo, a=(-5, 5, 0.1))
```

I do not know why it shows me no error and plot not my graph. (I code it in google colab)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUm4T.png)

Did i forget something or did i do something wrong?

Help.

Comment: `plt.plot(x, y, 'r.')` not `plt.plot(x, y)`. [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwUkN.png) you are plotting discrete points for a (-5, 5), an x (0, 20).